# Modify caller function stack?

Tags: c, stack

I have multiple handlers called by the same function. Imagine:

```
int (*pFunctions[])();
```

Handler calling function body:

```
{int a; extern int index; index[pFunctions]();}
```

Is there any-way to refer `a` inside the handlers?

Comment: Is `int (*pFunctions[])();` supposed to be `int (*pFunctions[])(void);` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not specified but irrelevant to the question - I'm pretty sure. However good spot on. On side note I prefer un-prototyped function declarations.

Comment: It is relevant as the best way would be to pass `a` as a parameter.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good idea